# Softlayer Api: Exception: Invalid data on the order for property: packageId. Package (835) requires a preset configuration

Tags: python, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

## background

Use sl_product_order.placeOrder api to order a vsi.
'dataCenter': 'ams03'

## exception

SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Order_InvalidData): Invalid data on the order for property: packageId. Package (835) requires a preset configuration.

## question

Package (835) requires a preset configuration means what?

How can I check which param is invalid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Package: 835 (Public Virtual Server)** is a new package that will be released very soon, meanwhile I recommend to continue using **Package: 46**

Comment: same config in other idc(hkg02) occurs this exception: SoftLayer_Exception_Order_InvalidLocation   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031137/softlayer-api-exception-the-location-provided-for-this-order-is-invalid/45036676#45036676

Comment: could you tell me when will Package: 835 release?  For my system need change the id templatly with Package: 46.

Comment: For sl_ordering_manager.get_package_id_by_type('VIRTUAL_SERVER_INSTANCE') always return 835.   While Package: 835 has not released, WoW~~

Comment: Probably the release will be end of the month

Comment: Hi, Ruber Cuellar, Now I use package 46 to placeorder but there is new Exception: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Invalid): The price 1 GB (204925) is not valid for package (46).  Does it mean I need to use package 835 instead ?